# Tablet Android Orientation when launch Activity

Tags: android-activity, screen-orientation, android

I have a strange problem on orientation handling on Samsung Tablets.
Basically, I have this app that it is supposed to run only in Landscape if running on tablet and portrait if i'm on a phone.
To do that I check on wich device I'm, and then I use the `onConfigurationChanged`  callback to set the right layout.
It works perfectly on the phone. But on tablet, if I'm holding it in portrait position, when launch another activity within the same app I see a flash oh the home screen (that's not cool), so the orientation (and also the android bar) goes in portrait position, the second activity is loaded in portrait (that's wrong) and just after a while the second activity change orientation to the right landscape position.
There is a way to simple load the second activity directly in landscape?
Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load any activity directly in landscape then mention screenOrientation directly in a particular activity inside the AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

this will load your activity directly in landscape orientation.

Comment: The problem is that I use the same activity for both phone (portrait) and tablet (Landscape) so I only know the activity orientation at runtime.

Comment: @FrancescoPuntillo for that case, you can also set the same thing programmatically as well.

Comment: Actually seems that was a problem with Auto-Rotiation. The only way that I've found and is setting the orientation inside the manifest.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are using the same activity just test for the android version and set the orientation programatically. Like this:

```
  if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11){
           //If build is tablet honeycomb or greater sdk such as 12, or 13
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);


    }
    else{
        //If device SDK is lower than 11 the view is set to PORTRAIT
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

You could also do

```
Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB
```

To test for tablet. This would be more specific to honeycomb. You also do HONEYCOMB_MR1 & MR2.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I've added this code to the onCreate method of the activity. But if I hold the tablet in portrait orientation from one activity to the second one...i see a flash of the home screen, a the activity is loaded in portrait and then rotate to the right landscape position.

Comment: hmmm....Interesting. So you are trying to load the second activity in landscape only?

Comment: Oh so its something you/us cant fix. but that would be the way above to test for a certain SDK version and display a screen orientation accordingly.

Comment: This isn't very smart, as new phones running Android 4 (API levels 14 & 15) will request landscape orientation. You should make use of device dimensions - large and x-large rather than API levels or other voodoo. After all, you're differentiating devices based on their size.

Comment: Very true, This answer was an options giving before 3.0. and You should add an answer using dimensions

Comment: And besides in my answer it is  : SDK > 11 meaning ANY API greater than 11, will have the orientation in the if statement